# Efficient way to merge two panda groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 groupby object as follows:

df1.last() => return a panda dataframe with stock_id and date as index:

```
                      close
stock_id, date     
a1        2005-12-31   1.1     
          2006-12-31   1.2
          ... 
          2017-12-31   1.3 
          2018-12-31   1.3
          2019-12-31   1.4 
a2        2008-12-31   2.1
          2009-12-31   2.4 
          ....
          2018-12-31   3.4
          2019-12-31   3.4
```

df2 => return a groupby object with id as index:

```
   
       stock_id,   date,        eps,    dps,
id 
1      a1         2017-12-01     0.2    0.03
2      a1         2018-12-01     0.3    0.02
3      a1         2019-06-01     0.4    0.01 
4      a2         2018-12-01     0.5    0.03
5      a2         2019-06-01     0.3    0.04
```

df2 is supposed to be used as reference to merge with df1 based on stock_id and year matching with df2 as df2 has lesser year value. The expected result as follows:

df2 merge with df1:

```
     stock_id,  date,  eps,   dps   close   ratio_eps, ratio_dps
id   a1         2017    0.2   0.03   1.3     0.2/1.3   0.03/1.3
     a1         2018    0.3   0.02   1.3     0.3/1.3     ...
     a1         2019    0.4   0.01   1.4     0.4/1.4     ...
     a2         2018    0.5   0.03   3.4     ...
     a2         2019    0.3   0.04   3.4     ...
```

The above can be done with for loop but it would be inefficient. Is there any pythonic way to achieve it ? 
How do i remove the day and month from both dataframe and use it as a key to match and join both table together efficiently ?

Comment: `df["date"] = df["date"].dt.year` to convert your `Datetime64` columns into year.

Comment: I get a key error when converting columns into year. Could be due to the date column being assigned as index.